# Async WCF call from WPC MVVM app Timing out and hanging the UI

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, asynchronous, timeout

I'm working on a WPF application and using MVVM. I'm calling a WCF service using the asynchronous methods and it's blocking the UI. Sometimes it just times out completely. I have website consuming the same services (*but not using the async calls*) with no problems. Here's my code and client config.

```cs
    private void ProcessLogin()
    {
        if (Username == null || Password == null)
            return;

        _working = true;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        Status = "Authenticating User";

        _authClient.BeginLogin(Username, Password, "", false, EndLogin, null);
    }

    protected void EndLogin(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        LoggedIn = _authClient.EndLogin(asyncResult);

        if (!LoggedIn)
        {
            Status = "Authentication Failure";
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }
        _working = false;
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

```xml
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<endpoint address="https://path_to_service:444/Authentication.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService"
            contract="AuthService.AuthenticationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" />
```

Comment: where is the code hanging? can you break onto the code when it is hung? Is any of the code updating the UI other than by databinding - for example `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();`?

Comment: Oh, it hangs on BeginLogin. The UI doesn't update until my EndLogin method runs so I don't see the status change and I don't see the buttons update. That's what CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); is for, to force the UI to check the CanExecute function again and enable/disable the login button.

Comment: try calling the EndLogin method on a separate thread.

Comment: It's asynchronous and handles the thread on its own. I switched to LoginAsync and LoginCompleted events and that works out correctly. Something about synchronization contexts. I also set useDefaultWebProxy to false in the binding and that removes the delay on first-time use of the client to. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an infinate loop, you are calling endlogin from within endlogin.